# Why does GeoServer WMS not work in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I am really new to Web GIS and currently I am trying to develop a web map using FOSS software. This is my code of OpenLayers and it is not working.

GeoServer URL

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sac:Luse&styles=&bbox=105097.8879663402,181965.81598811893,107146.57910105384,183739.10929816443&width=512&height=443&srs=EPSG:5235&format=application/openlayers&
```

OpenLayers code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'>
</script><script type='text/javascript'> 
var map; function init() 
{ 
   map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {}); 
   var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 'OpenLayers WMS', 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms', 
   {layers: 'sac:Luse'}, 
   {} 
); 
map.addLayer(wms); 
if(!map.getCenter()){ map.zoomToMaxExtent(); } } 
</script>
</head>
<body onload='init();'>
    <div id='map_element' style='width: 500px; height: 500px;'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how you first put your example together, but if you didn't know GeoServer Admin can generate an OpenLayers example of any layer for you through the Layer Preview page (v2.1.3 and possibly earlier, I've only used one version). You can then take what you want from the preview's source. By default the preview will only contain one layer (can be a layer group) but by playing with the URL you can view multiple layers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better if you explain what do you mean by "it not working" but my guess would be :
By default openlayers support EPSG:4326 projection. Here as I see you are requesting a layer in EPSG:5235 so you have to set projection explicitly to EPSG:5235.

It should be similar to this code :

```
var mapoptions = {
      maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(...),
      units: 'm',
      projection: "EPSG:5235",
    };
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map',mapoptions );
```

There should be several documentation about the basics of openlayers (particularly about projections and bounds that might be tricky from time to time)

Comment: Thanks.Really help full. "it not working" means map is not showing browser.I will try according to your answer